# Replace onclick function of an object using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How do I replace the destination URL on a button when using onclick?

```
<div id="my_button" onclick="window.location.replace('/destination1')">Button<div>
```

So it would look like this

```
<div id="my_button" onclick="window.location.replace('/destination2')">Button<div>
```

The following Javascript code doesn't work though. Why?

```
<script>
document.getElementById("my_button").onclick="window.location.replace('/destination2')"
<script>
```

Comment: onclick should be a function, your setting it as a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onclick that you have used in  tag - is html event attribute, but onclick in  tag, that you also tring to change - is div object property.

Both are like "onclick", but it's not the same.

So, if you want to make thing work, do this:

```
document.getElementById("my_button").onclick = () => window.location.replace('/destination2');
```

onclick div property need function(callback) not a string

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do it would be by adding a listener and preventing the default behavior of the event

```
document
  .getElementById('my_button')
  .addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    window.location.replace('/destination2');
  });
```

[working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-ktb5ss?file=index.js)

Answer (score 0):

`element.onclick` requires a function to be assigned and differs from the attribute `<node onclick="">` where the content will be wrapped up in a function automatically.

If you want to change the attribute, make use of `element.setAttribute("onclick", "...");`

```js
element.setAttribute("onclick", "window.location.replace('/destination2');");
```

Behaves similar to:

```js
element.onclick = function() { window.location.replace('/destination2'); };
```

Another solution would be using the [data-attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) which can be accessed by `element.dataset.name`.

Example:

```html
<div id="my_button" data-path="/destination2" onclick="window.location.replace(this.dataset.path);">Button</div>
```

And to change it:

```js
my_button.dataset.path = "/otherPath";
```